# stl_load_errors returning invalid timestamp format I can't figure out

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, type-conversion, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to use the `copy` function to create a table in Redshift. I've setup this particular field that keeps failing in my schema as a standard `timestamp` because I don't know why it would be anything otherwise. But when I run this statement:

```
copy sample_table
from 's3://aws-bucket/data_push_2018-10-05.txt'
                       credentials 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXX'
                       dateformat 'auto'
                       ignoreheader 1;
```

It keeps returning this error: `Invalid timestamp format or value [YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS]`

`raw_field_value`: `"2018-08-29 15:04:52"`

`raw_line`: `12039752|311525|"67daf211abbe11e8b0010a28385dd2bc"|98953|"2018-08-20"|"2018-11-30"|"active"|"risk"|||||||"sample"|15750|0|"2018-08-29 15:04:52"|"2018-08-29 16:05:01"`

There is a very similar table in our database (that I did not make) which has the aforementioned error value as `timestamp` and values for that field identical to `2018-08-29 15:04:52` so what's happening when I run it that's causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your copy command seems OK, and seems like you are missing `FORMAT as CSV  QUOTE AS '"'` AND   `DELIMITER AS '|'` parameters and It should work.

I'm here using some sample data and command to prove my case, to make it simple, I did made the table simple and covered all your data points though.

```
create table sample_table(
    salesid integer not null,
    category varchar(100),
    created_at timestamp,
    update_at timestamp );
```

Here goes your sample data `test_file.csv`,

```
12039752|"67daf211abbe11e8b0010a28385dd2bc"|"2018-08-29 11:04:52"|"2018-08-29 14:05:01"
12039754|"67daf211abbe11e8b0010a2838cccddbc"|"2018-08-29 15:04:52"|"2018-08-29 16:05:01"
12039755|"67daf211abbe11e8b0010a28385ff2bc"|"2018-08-29 12:04:52"|"2018-08-29 13:05:01"
12039756|"67daf211abbe11e8b0010a28385bb2bc |"2018-08-29 10:04:52"|"2018-08-29 15:05:01"
```

Here goes your copy command,

```
COPY sample_table FROM 's3://path/to/csv/test_file.csv'  CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXXXX'   FORMAT as CSV  QUOTE AS '"'  DELIMITER AS '|';
```

It will returns,

```
INFO:  Load into table 'sample_table' completed, 4 record(s) loaded successfully.
COPY
```

Though this command works fine, but if there are more issues with your data you could try `MAXERROR` option as well.

Hope it answers your question.